# Call function of Controller in TWIG

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a table with a list of clients and a button of edition , this button must call a function I defined in Controller

```
 <td>
  <a href="#" class="btn default btn-xs purple">
   <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit </a></td>
  <td>
```

How can it call a function editAction ?

Comment: You might be mixing up the concepts of client side code(javascript) with server side code (php).  Your browser cannot call editAction directly.  Maybe take a look at some ajax programming tutorials.

Comment: Thank you for your answer , Its my first project with symfony .. I'm little confused

Comment: The OP doesn't seem to know about the basics while he's doing the difficult parts.

Comment: It's just question of time @FranciscoPresencia , I have one week to translate a whole website from simple php to Symfony 2 :) Thank you for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, read [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html), [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html), and [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html) doc pages.
After that, your final template should look like this:

```
<table>
{% for client in clients %}
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="{{ path('MY_ROUTE', {'id':client.id}) }}" class="btn default btn-xs purple">
            <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit 
        </a>
    <td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: @Asmaa Take a look [this Jobeet series](http://www.intelligentbee.com/blog/category/php-and-symfony/page/3/) from Intelligentbee, it may help you..